# Comprehensive MD5 checksum tutorial

Tags: md5, checksum

What is the most comprehensive MD5 tutorial out there? I have been trying to implement a decent MD5 checksum program but I have not come across a tutorial that makes it really clear.

Any pointers would be appreciated, Thanks.

---

To clarify I would like to know how to implement it.

Comment: Tutorial for what? How to use it? How to implement it? What its cryptographic properties are? What it's appropriate for? What do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some explanation and [pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5#Pseudocode) of implementation on Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Nothing easier than that.
The following method will convert a given string and return the MD5 Hash of it.

```
public static string MD5Hash(string text)
{
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text))), “-”, “”);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to implement MD5 algorithm himself.

Comment: Why, because it's there of course ;)

Comment: Yep. Same reason I'm here. To learn